# escaped std::string to NSString*

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, string, nsstring

**I have:**

`std::string string = "\xae\xab\xe30"` (after "\xe30" sequence continue).

This data coming from echoprint-ios library after creating fingerprint for a music file on the iOS-device. This string contains `zlib`-compressed `base64` sequence.

UPD: sometimes this string can be with data like `.$\x18\x8a\x03` and I need your answer on that too.

**I need:**

parse this string into `NSString*` and pass it into `NSURL` to make a query to echoprint services.

**What's wrong:**

I can't parse `NSString*` object from this `std::string` by a lot of methods:

1. creating NSString object through `[NSString stringWithCString:string.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` - it returns `nil` on UTF8, something like what I need but incorrect data with encoding with UTF16/32 (but this is absolutely wrong, it should be ascii/utf8 string imo), or with NSAsciiStringEncoding it places in NSString object data with unreadable symbols (like from system symbols table).
2. any method which gets on input standard c-string (so it will be `string.c_str()`)

**Resume:**

I need help with translating this string to NSString object.

Comment: Did you check the iOS example in the echoprint site?

Comment: Exactly thus iOS example and ALL other examples (tried to find them on google, yandex and even bing) - they all casting `c string` to NSString* but all internet have is old examples. With iOS 6/7 it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading of all internet sites, forums, blog posts and etc I guess I've found the reason of the problem I've described above.

I couldn't believe this string is correct all the time and I was right - this is garbage.
C++ object of `Codegen`-class was incorrect all the time.

Goodly this problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901776/ios-6-and-7-doesnt-return-same-results).

This problem with codegen I've solved by modifying class to be objective-c++ class.
My fork of original echoprint-ios-example [here.](https://github.com/vityafx/echoprint-ios-sample) Feel free to get it and use.

Also a pull request to parent repository has been sent.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string string = "\xae\xab\xe30";
NSString * cocoaString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",string.c_str()];
```

or

```
NSString * cocoaString = [NSString stringWithCString:string.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

keep in mind that in c++ you can keep null chars in a string... but that wont be considered valid in an NSString and if you need to keep arbitrary data an NSData object will work better.

data example:

```
NSData * d = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void *) string.c_str() length:string.length()];
```

this will encapsulate arbitrary binary data with no regard for format.

Comment: Yes, my previous attempts and your example is correct. I've also tried to get correct value through NSData and etc, but it was just not needed - string always contained invalid data. So not my attemps, not your example can help. This is c++-objective-c problem.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I have included the data method which will ignore the utf8 constraints.

Comment: You, actually, right, but I don't know which answer to accept. I bet mine, because mine solves the root of the problem, but yours is answer on my question too. So I guess it would be better to accept mine to help people know how to fix problems with echoprint-ios-example.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy absolutely accept yours if it is the correct answer.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Just a minor correction: `NSString` considers `NUL` a valid character and can definitely contain it.

Comment: sorry @NikolaiRuhe I meant only to imply that [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",string.c_str()] will terminate early, and also a string must be valid in the encoding that you specify... there are scenarios that allow null chars.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to check the obvious, e30 (16) is equivalent to 3632 (10). This value is clearly more than 256, which can fit in 8 bytes. So there really is a error, compiler is right!